# Unit testing with gorm

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gorm

I have found a lot of questions regarding gorm mocking related to the old V1 package: [github.com/jinzhu/gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm). with the usage of [github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock).

I didn't find much with the v2.
My simple question is:

Suppose I have this storage package code:

```
...
type Storage struct {
    GormDB       *gorm.DB
    SqlDB        *sql.DB
    mutex        sync.Mutex
    ReadTimeout  int
    WriteTimeout int
}

func (ps *Storage) Open(settings *Settings) error {
    if err := settings.Validate(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    ps.mutex.Lock()
    defer ps.mutex.Unlock()

    if ps.GormDB != nil {
        return nil
    }

    gormDB, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN: settings.GetDSN(),
    }), &gorm.Config{
        SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s: %v", DBConnectError, err)
    }

    ps.GormDB = gormDB

    sqlDB, err := ps.GormDB.DB()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s: %v", DBRetrievalError, err)
    }

    ps.SqlDB = sqlDB
    ps.SqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(settings.MaxIdleConnections)
    ps.SqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(settings.MaxOpenConnections)

    ps.ReadTimeout = settings.ReadTimeout
    ps.WriteTimeout = settings.WriteTimeout

    return nil
}
```

How can I unit-test this function with a simple check that `gorm.Open` received the expected config?

I don't see any other way than passing the ORM interface to this method... It would be a tough solution to write a gorm interface and mock it myself...

Can anyone please provide a simple example of mocking such a function?

P.S.
I don't want to run the docker with Postgres for this test. It is a simple unit test, not integration.

**EDIT**:
Suppose I just want to mock the connection to make `gorm.Open` to not return an error. How can I do it?
`sqlmock.NewWithDSN(settings.GetDSN())` does not help

Comment: Why do you want to test `gorm.Open`?  You're just testing a third-party library, which has very low (essentially zero) value.

Comment: I don't want to test `gorm.Open`. I want to test `storage.Open` the unit test should include an expectation of passing an expected config to `gorm.Open`

Comment: Your question states differently.  You say "How can I unit-test this function with a simple check that gorm.Open received the expected config?"

This is testing `gorm.Open`. In other words: You probably don't need to do that.

Instead, focus on the effect you want your program/function to have. In the case of `Storage.Open`, there's not really much to test.  Presumably your call to `settings.Validate()` is already tested independently. Maybe you want to test that after calling `Open`, the idle max idle and max open connections are set as intended. You can do this easily with `go-sqlmock`.

Comment: @Flimzy, this is exactly the question, how iI can I do it easily with go-sqlmock

Comment: Well, you can't easily test `gorm.Open'`s options with go-sqlmock, which is what you actually asked about. What go-sqlmock will let you do is make a db connection that doesn't return an error. And to be honest, you may not need go-sqlmock for that at all.  I'm not sure if either `gorm.Open` or `.DB()` even make a network connection. If they don't, you won't need go-sqlmock at all.

Comment: `gorm.Open` opens an SQL connection. This method in V2 receives "GORM database dialector" and Gorm Options. I don't see how `go-sqlmock` can help me here since it mocks SQL db... If you have an example of how to mock the connection with gorm to not return error on Open, it would be great

Comment: It helps, because it allows you to open a connection without having an actual database.

Comment: I don't use GORM, so I'm not really able to throw together a quick example for you, but just pass in your DSN from go-sqlmock to your constructor function. It should be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.
Thanks to @flimzy for pointing me in the right direction.

To be able to test the storage open need to modify the function:

```
func (ps *Storage) Open(settings *Settings, postgresConfig *postgres.Config) error {
    if err := settings.Validate(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    ps.mutex.Lock()
    defer ps.mutex.Unlock()

    if ps.GormDB != nil {
        return nil
    }

    gormDB, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(*postgresConfig), &gorm.Config{
        SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s: %v", DBConnectError, err)
    }

    ps.GormDB = gormDB

    sqlDB, err := ps.GormDB.DB()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s: %v", DBRetrievalError, err)
    }

    ps.SqlDB = sqlDB
    ps.SqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(settings.MaxIdleConnections)
    ps.SqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(settings.MaxOpenConnections)

    ps.ReadTimeout = settings.ReadTimeout
    ps.WriteTimeout = settings.WriteTimeout

    return nil
}
```

To mock gorm connection we just pass `go-sqlmock` connection in the postgres config of the form postgres driver:

```
package postgres

import (
    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
)

var _ = Describe("Postgres Storage", func() {
    ... 
    Describe("Open", func() {
        Context("when settings are valid", func() {
            It("should open a DB connection and initialize storage", func() {
                sqlDB, sqlMock, _ := sqlmock.New()

                sqlMock.ExpectPing()
                err := storage.Open(settings, postgres.Config{Conn: sqlDB})
                dbStats := storage.sqlDB.Stats()

                Expect(err).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
                Expect(dbStats.MaxOpenConnections).To(Equal(settings.MaxOpenConnections))
                Expect(dbStats.OpenConnections).To(Equal(1))
                Expect(storage.ReadTimeout).To(Equal(settings.ReadTimeout))
                Expect(storage.WriteTimeout).To(Equal(settings.WriteTimeout))

                Expect(sqlMock.ExpectationsWereMet()).To(BeNil())
            })
        })
    })
})
```